# Do...Loop statement using an array for listbox

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Having trouble with the first part of this, i have the second all written out on paper but i can't plug it in without the first.

What i've come across is The btnAdd_Click procedure should add the number 1 to each elements ( i already have the elements i want to do) in the intQuantities array and also display the array's contents in the lstQuantities control; use the Do...Loop statement.

' class-level array
    Private intQuantities() As Integer = {45, 67, 2, 5, 90}

```
Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    ' adds 1 to each array value and then displays the array




    lstQuantities.Items.Clear()

End Sub

Private Sub btnSubtract_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubtract.Click
    ' subtracts 1 from each array value and then displays the array

    lstQuantities.Items.Clear()
```

I just can't grab the concept and have difficulty with Do...Loops, For...Next statements is what i'm doing for the subtract button.

Comment: Do you want to permanently change the values in the original array?...or just display the values + 1 in your ListBox?

Comment: display the values + 1 in my listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `Do...Loop` to iterate through an array is a little unusual, but all you need to do is increment an index variable inside the loop, until it is equal to the length of the `intQuantities` array.  You can use either form of `Do...Loop` - e.g. using `While`:

```
Dim i = 0
Do While i < intQuantities.Length
    intQuantities(i) += 1
    i += 1
Loop
```

Or using `Until`:

```
Dim i = 0
Do Until i = intQuantities.Length
    intQuantities(i) += 1
    i += 1
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you but how would get the input box to show up and for the input quantity number to show into the list box

Answer (score 0):

> Do you want to permanently change the values in the original
> array?...or just display the values + 1 in your ListBox? –  Idle_Mind
>
> 2 days ago       display the values + 1 in my listbox –  Taylor

Here's one way to do the plus one and minus one parts:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private intQuantities() As Integer = {45, 67, 2, 5, 90}

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        lstQuantities.DataSource = Array.ConvertAll(intQuantities, Function(x) x + 1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSubtract_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubtract.Click
        lstQuantities.DataSource = Array.ConvertAll(intQuantities, Function(x) x - 1)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks but i need the add to be a do...loop and then i'm having trouble with getting the data i entered in an inputbox to show up in the listbox

Comment: when clicking the add button when running the app an input box will show, but i can't get the data i enter to show in the listbox

Comment: So which is supposed to happen when you click the Add button?  Are you supposed to display all elements with 1 added to them?...or are you supposed to get a new entry and add it to the existing list?  Or are there two different "Add" buttons in play here?

Comment: There is one add button and once you click it an input box will pop up i have that i just don't know how to get it over from there to the list box.

Comment: nevermind about the input box i just need to get it to show up in the list box from what i have now

Dim i = 0
        Dim Quantities() As String = {45, 67, 2, 5, 90}

        ' Declare Elements and data

        Quantities(0) = "45"
        Quantities(1) = "67"
        Quantities(2) = "2"
        Quantities(3) = "5"
        Quantities(4) = "90"


        ' Do...Loop
        Do While i < Quantities.Length
            Quantities(i) += 1
            i += 1
            lstQuantities.Items.Add(Quantities)
        Loop